# Vulnerability of EAP-TLS simultaneous with PEAP-EAP-TLS?

Tags: peap, aaa

I am trying to make sense about the caution wirtten by Microsoft's engineers about `EAP`'s [Authentication method configuration settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/extensible-authentication-protocol/network-access?tabs=eap-tls#authentication-method-configuration-settings).

> ***Caution***
>
> *If a Network Access Server is configured to allow the same type of authentication method for a tunneled EAP method (e.g. PEAP) and a non-tunneled EAP method (e.g. EAP-MSCHAP v2), **there is a potential security vulnerability**. When you deploy both a tunneled EAP method and EAP (which isn't protected), don't use the same authentication type. For example, if you deploy PEAP-TLS, don't also deploy EAP-TLS. This is because if you require the protection of the tunnel, it serves no purpose to permit the method to be executed outside of the tunnel as well.*

(Emphasis is mine.)

I understand that deploying both `EAP-TLS` and `PEAP-EAP-TLS` as alternatives does not make much sense, since I do not see any benefit of one among the other (or vice-versa). But out of the added complexity of dealing with two different protocols, I fail to see where are the potential vulnerabilities.

What am I missing?

In the context of Microsoft's offer of a RADIUS server, there are only two basic EAP protocols (`EAP-TLS` and `EAP-MSCHAPv2`) which can be combined, or not, with `PEAP-`. I can certainly see the difference between `EAP-MSCHAPv2` on one side (a bad choice these days), and `PEAP-EAP-MSCHAPv2`. In this particular case, I can see where the vulnerability might be, akin to comparing `http:` with `https:`. But it seems to me the problem then is exclusively with `EAP-MSCHAPv2`, not about the mix of any EAP protocol to be used with or without PEAP tunnel encapsulation.